# CentOS Server How to Keep PHP Socket Server running?

Tags: php

I have tried the nohup php socket.php & and the server does start and remain started after the ssh window is closed. But when I got back a while later, its not running again. How can I keep this running?

Comment: Please post the code.  For some reason the script is probably terminating and getting out of the connection loop.  Can't say without code though.  Also check the error log for any possible errors that are causing it to die after some time.

Comment: It's likely your server is encountering a PHP error of some kind and exiting. If the process is robust, the server will stay running using `nohup`.

Comment: Would there be a way for me to tell that? I really cant post the code.

Comment: this sounds like a job for node.js and socket.io instead of php sockets.